# need help to write a query about this db

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have this DB and I need help with this query

> Find the customer ID, first name, last name and the movie Name 
>   of the customer that bought the most ticket in that day

[image: img]

I found the customer who bought the highest number of tickets in that day, now I need to find the movies that he bought tickets for

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(*) 'bought'
FROM customer c JOIN ticket t ON c.customerId=t.customerId
GROUP BY c.customerId
HAVING bought=(SELECT MAX(T1.CNT)
                    FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT 
                          FROM customer c JOIN ticket t ON c.customerId=t.customerId
                          GROUP BY c.customerId) AS T1)
```

Comment: Is there an update to this question, did the solution provided work?

Answer (score 0):

So without building the database and populating it with dummy data I can't test this, but I think I found a solution for you.

```
     SELECT C.CUSTOMERID, C.FIRSTNAME, C.LASTNAME, M.TITLE 
    FROM CUSTOMER C JOIN TICKET T ON C.CUSTOMERID = T.CUSTOMERID JOIN SHOWS S ON T.SHOWNUMBER = S.SHOWNUMBER JOIN MOVIE M ON M.MOVIEID = S.MOVIEID 
    WHERE C.CUSTOMERID IN(
SELECT C1.CUSTOMERID FROM(
SELECT CUST.CUSTOMERID, COUNT(*) 'BOUGHT' 
FROM CUSTOMER CUST JOIN TICKET TICK ON CUST.CUSTOMERID = TICK.CUSTOMERID 
GROUP BY CUST.CUSTOMERID 
HAVING BOUGHT = (SELECT MAX(T1.CNT) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM CUSTOMER CUSTO JOIN TICKET TICKE ON CUSTO.CUSTOMERID = TICKE.CUSTOMERID GROUP BY CUSTO.CUSTOMERID)AS T1) AS C1);
```